# Getting Unexpected Output when using array in struct

Tags: c++, struct

I am new to the world of programming in c++. I am getting an unexpected thing when running following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef struct person
{
    int age;
    char* name;
    float salary;
    bool gender;
} prsn;

enum Gender
{
    male,
    female
};

int main()
{
    prsn p1;
    p1.name[0] = 'A';
    p1.name[1] = 'd';
    p1.name[2] = 'i';
    p1.name[3] = 't';
    p1.name[4] = 'y';
    p1.name[5] = 'a';
    p1.age = 17;
    p1.salary = 100000;
    p1.gender = male; // enum used

    cout << "Person p1's info:\nName: " << p1.name << "\nAge: " << p1.age << "\nSalary: " <<
    p1.salary << "\nGender: " << p1.gender;

    return 0;
}
```

When running above code at printing p1.name always getting 4 random characters different everytime.
My g++ version: `g++.exe (i686-posix-dwarf-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0`, using Visual Studio Code(IDE).
Thanks!

Comment: `p1.name` is not initialized, `std::string` might be a better choice (and then `p1.name = "Aditya";`).

Comment: Your `name` member is a pointer ... but whither does it point? You will need to either allocate some memory and point to that, or (probably better) declare `name` as an array of characters.

Comment: `bool gender;`... Whereas you declare an `enum` for that :/

Comment: @AdrianMole From tutorials of C++ I came to know that we can initialise array by this.

Comment: @jarod42 Can you please explain how to use std::string

Comment: Like [that](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e55dd9a9a9e38454).

Comment: Whoever told you that `char*` is an array is somebody you shouldn't trust in C++ programming matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you can learn on your mistake lets first see what is wrong with your code.

```
typedef struct person
{
    int age;
    char* name;
    float salary;
    bool gender;
} prsn;
```

`char *` is pointer to some address. So if you do not use `new` it will point to random address that was previously written to the memory.

Your alternatives are to use constructor and allocate some memory:

```
struct person () : name (new name(10)) {
}
```

or to use `std::string`.

```
typedef struct person
{
    int age;
    std::string name;
    float salary;
    bool gender;
} prsn;
```

One more note that points me to the thing that you are learning `C++` from wrong place is

```
typedef struct person {
} prsn;
```

In `C` this is done to avoid initializing your struct with:

```
int main () {
    struct person p1;
    ...
}
```

In `C++` you can easily do it this way:

```
int main () {
    person p1;
    ...
}
```

remember `struct` is a `class` with public members by default in `C++`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct person
{
    int age;
    char* name;
    float salary;
    bool gender;

    person () : age (0), char (new char[20]()), salary (0.0), gender (true) {
    }
};

enum Gender
{
    male,
    female
};

int main()
{
    person p1;
    p1.name[0] = 'A';
    p1.name[1] = 'd';
    p1.name[2] = 'i';
    p1.name[3] = 't';
    p1.name[4] = 'y';
    p1.name[5] = 'a';
    p1.age = 17;
    p1.salary = 100000;
    p1.gender = male; // enum used

    cout << "Person p1's info:\nName: " << p1.name << "\nAge: " << p1.age << "\nSalary: " <<
    p1.salary << "\nGender: " << p1.gender;

    return 0;
}
```

There are some more errors in your code, so my suggestion is pls switch your book, website whatever you are learning C++ from.

As suggested, you should avoid using raw pointers in C++. Instead uses `std::shared_ptr()` and `std::unique_ptr()`.

Comment: Thanks @KPCT. I must switch for learning.

Comment: You need to use square brackets following new. But basically you should not use raw pointers/new for owned memory at all . . .

Comment: @ArminMontigny I know you should use unique or shard ptrs, but this was based on OPs question and I am pointing out where is he making mistakes. I do appreciate your input.